# MySQLのバージョン間でのスキーマ違いを吸収する方法

Tags: mysql

古いMySQLをリプレースする際に、新しいMySQLサーバを準備して、mysqldump等でデータを移行することが多いと思います。
その際にバージョン間でスキーマが異なってくることがあるのですが(特に4.x系→5.x系)、その際にスキーマを変更する効率的な方法があれば教えて下さい。
小さな規模であれば、エラーになった箇所を手作業で変更して・・・が可能なのですが、規模が大きくなるととても大変です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4.xとありますが，4.0と4.1でも差がありますのでご注意ください．

例えば4.0ではutf-8やbinaryがcharacter setにサポートされておりません．
MySQL 4.0の`/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index`をご覧いただくと，正式にサポートされているcharacter setが分かります．

```
# sql/share/charsets/Index
#
# This file lists all of the available character sets.  Please keep this
# file sorted by character set number.


big5               1
czech              2
dec8               3
dos                4
german1            5
hp8                6
koi8_ru            7
latin1             8
latin2             9
swe7              10
usa7              11
ujis              12
sjis              13
cp1251            14
danish            15
hebrew            16
# The win1251 character set is deprecated.  Please use cp1251 instead.
win1251           17
tis620            18
euc_kr            19
estonia           20
hungarian         21
koi8_ukr          22
win1251ukr        23
gb2312            24
greek             25
win1250           26
croat             27
gbk               28
cp1257            29
latin5            30
latin1_de         31
```

> [参考]
>
> - ttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-unicode.html

また，CHAR型を宣言する時の長さの単位も変化しています．

MySQL 4.1以前では，`CHAR(30)`は30バイト分の長さを示していましたが，MySQL 4.1以降の`CHAR(30)`は30文字に意味が変わっています．
ちなみに1文字あたりのバイト数も，日本語は3バイトまでだったり4バイトまでだったり，MySQLのバージョンによって様々です．

> [参考]
>
> - ttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/char.html
> - ttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html
> - ttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

どちらも4.0と4.1の違いについてでしたが，4.0から5.xでも同様の問題は発生しうるのでコメントさせていただきました．

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。昔4.0から4.1に上げようとして、sjisコードがなくなった(正確には覚えてません)ので諦めた記憶があります。セキュリティ対策やEOLなどでバージョンを上げたいのはやまやまなのですが、バージョン間での違いを検証するところまで手が回らず、今に至っています。

Answer (score 2):

バージョン間でスキーマが異なるのはおそらくMySQL自体が利用する管理テーブルのカラムだと思うので mysql_upgrade コマンドを試されるのはいかがでしょうか。

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。
mysql_upgradeというコマンドは知りませんでした。
バックアップを取得してやってみようと思います。

ただ、エラーが発生している箇所がmysqlデータベースではなくて、自分で作成したデータベース内なのです。
今確認できているのが
「TYPE=MyISAM」→「ENGINE=MyISAM」
「timestamp(14)」→「timestamp」
の2か所です。